# How do scan an opened book with openCV and Python and take the page that is focused in?

Tags: python, opencv, draw, crop, scanning

I need to scan an opened book, in fact it is an agenda; and apply to it a four point transform to crop it a save it but it only requires 4 points and it sometimes takes 6 or 5 points and draws an incomplete rectangle
So it draws it and tries to close it... but it fails at applying the 4 point transform
[Filters Applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5iGe.jpg)

```
import cv2
import imutils


def primer_filtro(archivo):
image = cv2.imread("images/" + archivo)
image = imutils.resize(image, height=800)

# Hacer Gris y desenfoque Gaussiano
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

# Definir bordes
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 250)
# Definir pixeles
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Encontrar contorno
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Dibujar contorno
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 6:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -5, (0, 0, 0), 60)
        cv2.imwrite("images/find_book.jpg", image)
        cv2.imshow("Final", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

```
import cv2
from skimage.filters import threshold_adaptive
from pyimagesearch import imutils
from pyimagesearch.transform import four_point_transform


def segundo_filtro(archivo, original):
original = cv2.imread("images/" + original)
original = original.copy()
while True:
    imagen = archivo
    image = cv2.imread("images/" + imagen)
    try:
        ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
        # original = image.copy()
        image = imutils.resize(image, height=800)
        break
    except:
        print "Intentando de nuevo"

# Convertir imagenes en gris
# gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = image
cv2.imshow("Immg", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Aplicar desenfoque Gaussiano
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Bordeado de imagen
bordeado = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 450)
# bordeado = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 250)
cv2.imshow("Bordeada", bordeado)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Encontrar los contornos tomando en cuenta los mas grandes
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(bordeado.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]
# Buscar en el contorno
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    # Dibujar Contorno
    if len(approx) == 6:
        approx[4] = approx[0]
        approx[5] = approx[1]
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -5, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    elif len(approx) == 4:
        print "Tiene {0} puntos".format(len(approx))
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -5, (125, 0, 0), 5)
    cv2.imwrite("images/lforehead.jpg", image)
    # print "Este tiene {0} puntos".format(len(approx))
    cv2.imshow("Contorno", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

try:
    frentear = four_point_transform(original, approx.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
    frentear = cv2.cvtColor(frentear, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frentear = threshold_adaptive(frentear, 251, offset=10)
    frentear = frentear.astype("uint8") * 255
    cv2.imwrite("images/escaneo.jpg", frentear)
    cv2.imshow("Frenteado", imutils.resize(frentear, height=650))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
except:
    exit()
```

Comment: did you see [Flattening images of curled pages](https://mzucker.github.io/2016/08/15/page-dewarping.html)

Comment: i did not test it.please answer your question after test it. so people know it is good.

Comment: OK, I'll test it as soon as possible.

Comment: It works with its examples, trying to modify it wont asure you it would work with your images... I tried something more simple: Cropping image by percentage and applying threshold_adaptive.